# Deploy ASP.NET application in the same web site as Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, session-state

I am trying to deploy the Bugtracker.NET tool (http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html), which is a normal ASP.NET 2.0 application, into the default web site of an IIS which already has Sharepoint installed in it. The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 and Sharepoint Services 3.0.

The question is that when I execute the application, I get a NullReferenceException because HttpContext.Current.Session is null, and I think that this could be due to a problem with the configuration of the web site, as the application runs perfect in web sites with no Sharepoint installed.

I already know that Sharepoint customizes the web site with handles, modules and so on, that all applications in the web site inherit, modifying their behavior. I have already given to the ASP.NET application Full trust level, enabled Anonymous authentication and InProc session state, but I am still getting that HttpContext.Current.Session is null. Even changing the app pool from Wss3AppPool to DefaultAppPool does not succeed.

Maybe someone could tell me which settings do I need to tweak in the web site in order to avoid this exception.

Many thanks in advance.

José Antonio Arroba

Comment: Don't know if it'll work, but maybe you can create a virtual directory inside the website, or a web application within the website (in IIS). 
I've done something in the past, but don't know if it'll work with session variables though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into [Managed Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802766(office.12).aspx) and excluding the path to your bugtrackernet app.

However why do you HAVE to use the default web application?

Why not keep your life simple and setup a new IIS web application on a separate host header or subdomain and host your app there.

e.g.

http://bugtracker.yourdomain/

or just

http://bugtracker/

Comment: Ryan, you are completely right. I forgot that with host headers I could separate different web sites that listen at the same port and protocol. I have set up a different web site that way and now the app works like a charm. Thanks as well for the tip with the Managed Paths in Sharepoint!